# struts 2 Action chain getting different values of same object

Tags: struts2

I have an action class where I am passing value from jsp, then modifying that value in action class 1 and then due to action chain, another action2 is being called.
In action 2 I am getting the original value

`value= 100// in jsp
action 1: value*10= 1000// action 1 
go to action 2`

I want modified value to go to action 2 `i.e. 1000//`value modified in action 1. but I am getting`10// i.e. original value.`

can you tell me what to do in order to use values obtained from action 1.

struts.xml

```
<action name="action1" class="vaannila.action.action1">
    <result name="success" type="chain">action2
    </result>
</action>
<action name="action2" class="vaannila.action.action2">
    <result name="success" type="dispatcher">result.jsp
    </result>
</action>
```

action 1

```
public class action1 extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware{ 
    public String execute() throws Exception{
        System.out.println("original"+ pSB.getvalue() ); // getting 10
        pSB.getvalue((pSB.getvalue()*10));

        System.out.println("modified"+ pSB.getvalue() ); // getting 100 
                return "success";   
    }
}
```

action 2:

```
public class action2 extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware{ 
    public String execute() throws Exception{
        System.out.println("original"+ pSB.getvalue() ); // getting 10 instead of 100.
            return "success";   
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a typo here: `pSB.getvalue((pSB.getvalue()*10));` should start with `pSB.setvalue` of course, but that was just in creating the question because the value wouldn't be 100 on the next line... also it is annoying to see partial actions. That is I WANT to see the getters and setters on both actions. It's probably something simple so cut and paste, otherwise people will see silly typos and tell you that's the reason for the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the action 1 as follows

```
public class action1 extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware{ 
public String execute() throws Exception{
    System.out.println("original"+ pSB.getvalue() ); // getting 10
    pSB.setvalue((pSB.getvalue()*10));

    System.out.println("modified"+ pSB.getvalue() ); // getting 100 
            return "success";   
}
```

the mistake is that you have calculated the value in the action1 class but did not updated it back to session